# Вопрос про сужение типов

Tags: java, преобразование-типов, int, примитивы

Хотел бы получить объяснение про преобразование бесконечности к целочисленным типам.
Например:

```
double d = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
System.out.println((int)d); // 2147483647
System.out.println((int)0x7ff0000000000000L); // 0
System.out.println((int)(double)0x7ff0000000000000L); // 2147483647
```

Я создаю переменную d типа double и присваиваю ей значение положительной бесконечности. Далее, я преобразовываю эту бесконечность к типу int и на выходе получаю значение 2147483647.

Вопрос 1: почему дробная положительная бесконечность преобразовалась в максимальное возможное значение для int?

Далее, среда разработки показывает, что POSITIVE_INFINITY это некое число в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления (0x7ff0000000000000L). На выходе мы получаем, что это число в int будет равно 0. Используя обычный калькулятор перевода чисел из одной системы в другую получим число (0x7ff0000000000000L) в двоичной системе - 111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.

Вопрос 2. Последние 32 бита равны 0, старшие биты откидываются и поэтому int равен 0?
Вопрос 3. Почему Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY(0x7ff0000000000000L) имеет на конце литерал L? Это же не лонг?
Вопрос 4. Почему, когда в 4 строчке кода я вывожу:

```
System.out.println((int)(double)0x7ff0000000000000L);
```

Результатом получается снова максимальное число для int? Как происходит в данном случае сужение типа?
Прошу объяснить эти моменты. Хочу докопаться до истины.

Comment: все примитивы зациклены. максимальный инт +1 равен минимальный инт

Comment: `POSITIVE_INFINITY это некое число в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления (0x7ff0000000000000L)`. Это всё-таки неправда. Вещественные числа хранятся совсем иначе, нежели целые.

Comment: Приведение `0x7ff0000000000000L`  к `int` не имеет никакого отношения к `double`. Это просто несвязанные вещи. А последовательность битов, соответствующая в шестнадцатеричной записи значению `0x7FF0000000000000`, обозначает бесконечность, потому что в этой записи [степень заполнена единицами, а мантисса нулями](https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?hexadecimal=7FF0000000000000).